# How to split money by weighted amounts?

Tags: javascript, split, currency, distribution

My goal is to split some total `T` between `N` things, where each thing has some weight `w[i]` that's between 0 and 1.

There's two things going on here simultaneously:

- I'm using sliders (JavaScript) for the weight selection, and I'm trying to ensure that the sum of all weights is 1.
- Thanks to the first thing, the bulk of the per-thing amount is fairly straightforward, it's just `w[i] × T`.

However, there's a few quirks:

- Because the sliders have pixel precision, the sum of all of the weights is typically *close* to one, but often slightly off by a few hundredths.
- Because the lowest unit is cents, I can't evenly split $1.00 between three things; something has to get the extra cent. Right now, I'm trying give/take the extra/missing cent to/from the last thing.

With all of this, I have two requirements:

- Be as accurate as possible with the Weighted distribution.
- The per-thing amounts **must** add up to the original total.

What's the best JavaScript solution, assuming I have a function like this:

```
/**
 * Calculates the Weighted Distribution between an arbitrary number
 * of people, and returns it.
 *
 * @param  array  weights  The weights for each thing (Sums up to nearly 1)
 * @param  int    total    The total amount to be split (in cents)
 *
 * @return array  The Weighted Distribution (each element is in cents)
 */
function calc(weights, total)
{
    // Determine the total number of Things
    var things = weights.length;

    /* Do stuff */
    return distribution;
}
```

Note that I'm sending everything in using cents. This should help the calculation process, as any currency denoted as a float is invalid.

Comment: so, what's the question? And what is the problem?

Comment: My question is: What's the best JavaScript solution for splitting a specified total (in cents) between a specified number if weights.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? SO is not for getting your Job done by someone else. Its about getting help with specific problems.

Comment: This is a specific problem, and it's for a personal project, not a job. As I stated in the OP, every solution I've tried has split the money semi-correctly, failing in scenarios where the total can't be split evenly. It's typically off by one or two cents.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what your problem is. Nevertheless, for things like counting weights precisely, divide up to cents etc you'd better use decimals, not floats,  in your calculations, like https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/

Comment: My currency data types are integers, only the weights are floats. Because the sliders come from an external library, I don't think that I can change the weights, as the User uses the sliders to select their weights.